# mysql timestamp updating error

Tags: php, date, timestamp

when i'm editing information from db, there is problem with date. My date got TIMESTAMP data type. When i save(UPDATE) information, the date is 0000-00-00 00:00:00. 
My SQL query is -

```
UPDATE `news`
SET `category`='$category',
  `title`='$title',
  `img`='$file',
  `short_content`='$short_content',
  `content`='$long_content',
  `date`=$date,
  `lang`='$lang' 
WHERE `id`='$id'
```

$date can be something like 2013-16-06 20:35:12 but its saving as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the date:

```
`date`='$date',
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date string is either empty or most likely is formatted differently that your mysql table field expects it to be. 0000-00-00 00:00:00 is mysql default value

Answer (score 0):

Just surround your date with quotes

```
`date`='$date',
```

This is not an integer column, a datetime maybe, so you need to use quotes around your date